# Is this outlet ok for an AC condenser?

Tags: electrical, hvac

I am planning to install a MR Cool AC split unit. The 18k one.

I found out that close where the condenser will be I have an outlet, but I don't know if it will work for the AC installation.

My questions:

- Is this plug okay to be outside or I need to put some kind of box around it?
- In the installation guide it says it needs a 15A breaker. What is that and how do I install it?

[image]

Comment: *"I need a 15A breaker. What is that and how do I install it?"*. Just stop. Hire an electrician before you kill yourself or burn your house down.

Comment: Plugs are at the end of cords. This is an outlet or receptacle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Likely your 18KBTU unit needs 15A @ 240V, and what you have there will be 15 or 20A at 120V. **Edit:** *actually it appears to need 18A @ 208-230V, which requires a 20A @ 240V breaker, though it can have as much as a 30A @ 240V breaker.*

Honestly, if you are asking what a 15A breaker *is*, you *might* want to hire an electrician to run the circuit. Or get some current educational materials about home wiring and study up quite a bit, then ask lots of questions and proceed very slowly and carefully because "you don't know what you don't know" and that's where it's rather easy to get bitten badly.

A circuit breaker is a thing that lives in an electrical panel (either a "main panel" or a "subpanel") which limits current through the attached wires by shutting off when current is above its rated value. In the USA/Canada they come single-width or "one-pole" for 120V circuts such as the NEMA 5-15 receptacle you show, and double-width or "two pole" for 240V circuits typical of MOST mini-splits.

A 15A rated breaker will pass 15A. It will run a long time before tripping (shutting off) for very slight overloads (15.5 or 16A), and will shut off rather quickly for severe overloads (say 30A.)

That style of outlet is "OK to be outside" if nothing's plugged into it - these days a so-called "In Use Cover" is required so that you can actually have cables plugged in without everything getting wet and shorting out in the rain.

Comment: Try to find somone who won't mind you looking, asking questions, and learning, if possible.

Comment: Yep! Will do that. One quick question. In the manual online for the 18k mini split, I see this:  VOLTAGE 208-230 V -.MAX FUSE BREAKER 30 A - Does this mean 240 and a need of a breaker of 30a? I want to make sure I ask the proper installation to the technician

Comment: US-Market stuff that says 208-230 will run on 240 (which is typically what you actually have, unless you are in an area where you have 120V and 208V, rather than 120V & 240V - depends on the distribution setup.) This sort of unit is generally marked for *both* "Minimum Circuit Ampacity" which may be the 15A you found earlier, and "Maximum Overcurrent Protection" which is what you just quoted. You need at least the MCA, but you can't have a breaker/supply larger than the MOP. As an inverter-drive variable speed unit, there's no real need to go beyond the MCA. Hand them the manual.

Comment: Assuming it's the "4th Gen" unit MCA appears to be 18A and MOP is 30, so a 20A @240V circuit should be adequate. For old-tech compressors you might have wanted to spend more on a 30A circuit, for this you should not need to. But you may also have a slightly different model in mind, they have many similar models.

Comment: @Ecnweral - yep, is the 4th gen. This one to be specific: MrCool E Star DIY 4th Gen 18k BTU Ductless Mini-Split Heat Pump Complete System 208-230V/60Hz
Item # ‌1688044

Comment: @Nobita feel free to get a couple books on home electrical and get properly up to speed.  It's not terribly hard.  Alternately you could physically install the unit and then hire a pro to run the electrical to it.

Answer (score 7):

### That plug is useless... but not *entirely* useless.

It can't power the mini-split for two reasons: #1 it's the wrong voltage (you need 240V, [which we have in the US](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4)) and #2 mini-splits require dedicated circuits and be hardwired, as the instructions tell you.

However, Code requires that when you install a heat pump (that's what you have there)... there must exist a 120V outlet within 25' of it, so the maintainer can plug in their vacuum pump.

That socket is *grandfathered* since it was installed prior to modern code requirements.  Under modern Code it would require a) an "in-use" cover to (badly) provide weather protection while in-use, and b) a sticker that says "GFCI Protected" due to being fed from a GFCI protection module inside the house. Some GFCI protection modules contain 2 sockets on the front; you've seen those; but they're not the only kind.

### The heat pump, though.

That thing is [a heat pump](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto) actually.  AKA a "reverse cycle air conditioner" which can switch, pumping heat *into the house* at 200-600% efficiency compared to running an electric heater.  Since it's *only moving* the heat, it gets to run over-unity. Like Technology Connections says, it's [like a physics cheat code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI&t=0s) :)

The installation will also need a 2-pole disconnect switch near the heat pump.  These are quite inexpensive, what, $20-ish? and can be as simple as a little plastic pullout handle - though I prefer a proper knife switch, because if the pullout is overheating you'll just get a handful of melted plastic lol.

The cable is ordinary stuff, it's only a 20A circuit (at 240V, note that voltage doesn't require special cable)... however it will need outdoor rated cable such as UF wherever the wire is outdoors (but NM cable can come through the wall straight into the back of the disconnect). From the disconnect to the heat pump, people generally use a flexible whip or FMC that is outdoor-rated.

It will need a special 2-pole 240V breaker, which takes (or at least occupies) 2 breaker spaces.  How to get that varies by circuit panel.

Comment: MCA appears to be 18A, so a 20A circuit.

Comment: Plus one for "badly" in "it would require a) an "in-use" cover to (badly) provide weather protection"

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing a split heat pump, the outside unit is usually hard-wired, not plugged in, at least on the ones I've seen.

Comment: "Hardwided but with a local disconnect switch"

Comment: @criggie: Right. Assuming that this is what the querant was asking about..

Answer (score 1):

There's one unmentioned flaw in your plan: not only is that circuit not 240v, it's also likely one in a series of outlets. Your AC unit wants to be on its own dedicated circuit. Most outlets are on a circuit that run between multiple outlets. All my exterior outlets share a circuit, and it's very likely yours do as well. It wouldn't go very well to tie into this circuit (even if it would work at 120v) and then you plug some yard equipment in elsewhere in Summer and blow the circuit. A 15A circuit is 1800W. Most 120v mini-splits take at least 1000W, bare minimum.

Put all HVAC like this on its own circuit. That's a major reason they talk so much about needing a 15 amp breaker. They're assuming you're going to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

> I am planning to install a MR Cool AC split unit. The 18k one.

Personally or are you hiring a professional? Did you buy it yet?

I recommend reading the instructions from front-to-back before starting any work and watch at least 3 professional YouTube videos.

> I found out that close where the condenser will be I have an outlet, but I don't know if it will work for the AC installation.

Condensers don't typically rely on outlets unless you're installing a window A/C unit.

> Is this plug okay to be outside or I need to put some kind of box around it?

No, it's not okay. It's the wrong voltage and doesn't provide all-season use anyways. You can only use it in dry weather and the flap should be closed during any sort of precipitation.

Outdoor condensers are typically hardwired and follow this order:

1. Condenser

   - Don't forget the condenser pad or wall-mounting bracket
2. Waterproof whip
3. Outdoor disconnect
4. 10/3 wire back to electrical panel

   - 12/3 might be okay? I would overprovision anyways in case you find that 18k is insufficient
5. 240v breaker rated for 15 amps in your situation

> In the installation guide it says it needs a 15A breaker. What is that and how do I install it?

It's a breaker, rated for 15 amps.

Based on the absolute inexperience I read in your question; if you try to do this yourself then I hope your affairs are in order because your panel will gladly deliver hundreds of amps to your heart depending on how wrongly you touch something. This isn't something you can muddle through haphazardly.